# Getting distinct characters from a string

Tags: java, string, character

I know there is an easier way to solve this problem statement now. But this is something i tried and wasn't able to debug.

This is my code.

```
String str="java is a programming language";
int flag=0,k=0;
char unique[]=new char[256];
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
  for(int j=i+1;j<str.length();j++){
    if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(j))
        flag++;
  }
  System.out.println(flag); //printing flag values
  if(flag==0){
     unique[k]=str.charAt(i);
     System.out.println(unique[k]); //printing array values
     k++;
  }
}
```

And this is my output.

```
Enter the sentence:
java is a programming language
0
j
5
5
9
12
13
13
15
18
19
19
20
20
23
23
25
26
26
26
27
29
29
29
30
30
31
31
31
31
31
Unique characters:
j
```

I want to understand from where these number values are getting printed. I was certain printing flag values and array values will give me single digit numbers. What are all these double digit numbers?

Comment: At `System.out.println(flag);` you are printing value held by `flag`, but since you never reset it to 0 for each character it holds count from previous iterations.

Comment: "I know there is an easier way to solve this problem": `s.chars().distinct().mapToObj(i -> (char) i).forEach(System.out::println)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has the following problems:

1. Not resetting the value of `flag`.
2. Printing `flag` for each value of `i` whereas you wanted to print it only on finding a unique character.
3. You are starting the loop with `j` from `i + 1` and this way, you will not be able to compare the characters before the index, `i + 1`.

Some additional things you may also like to do are:

1. Filtering only non-blank characters.
2. Printing the array only up to the value of `k`.
3. Not fixing the size of `unique[]` to `256`. If all characters in `str` are unique, the required size of `unique[]` will be equal to the length of `str`. Thus, the maximum required size of `unique[]` is equal to `str.length()`. However, it is always better to use a `List` if the size needs to be dynamic.

Store and print unique characters as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "java is a programming language";
        int flag, k = 0;
        char unique[] = new char[str.length()];// This array can have a maximum length equal to the length of str

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            flag = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
                if (i != j && str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j)) {
                    flag++;
                }
            }
            if (flag == 0 && !String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)).isBlank()) {
                unique[k] = str.charAt(i);
                k++;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Unique characters: ");
        for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
            System.out.print(unique[i] + (i < k - 1 ? "," : "\n"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Unique characters: j,v,s,p,o,l,u,e
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to **reset the counter(flag)** before adding to it in the next iteration.

```
flag=0;
for(int j=i+1;j<str.length();j++){
if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(j))
    flag++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="java is a programming language";
int flag=0,k=0;
char unique[]=new char[256];
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
  flag = 0;
  for(int j=i+1;j<str.length();j++){
    if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(j))
        flag++;
  }
  System.out.println(flag); //printing flag values
  if(flag==0){
     unique[k]=str.charAt(i);
     System.out.println(unique[k]); //printing array values
     k++;
  }
}
```